# How to write single elements of a list at the end of a csv line with Python?

Tags: python, list, csv, writer

The code below adds the full list `['x', 'y', 'z']` as a single element of the csv. What I am trying to get is `'x'; 'y'; 'z';` at the end of the line. How?

```
import csv
toto = ['x', 'y', 'z']
with open('res.csv', 'w', newline='') as resfile:
    reswriter = csv.writer(resfile, delimiter=';')
    reswriter.writerow(['Number', 'A', 'B', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])    # header.
    reswriter.writerow(['001', 'a', 'b', toto])
```

Comment: `reswriter.writerow(['001', 'a', 'b'] + toto)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add asterisk `*` to `toto`:

```
import csv
toto = ['x', 'y', 'z']
with open('res.csv', 'w', newline='') as resfile:
    reswriter = csv.writer(resfile, delimiter=';')
    reswriter.writerow(['Number', 'A', 'B', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])    # header.
    reswriter.writerow(['001', 'a', 'b', *toto])   # <--- note the *
```

Writes `res.csv`:

```
Number;A;B;X;Y;Z
001;a;b;x;y;z
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!